# Ffmpeg commands in c# with variables

Tags: c#, html, ffmpeg

I am using the following command to slice a live stream in pieces:

```
ffmpeg -i InputStreamURL -acodec aac -strict -2 -vcodec libx264 -hls_wrap 100 -f hls -hls_time 20 /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8
```

This is working fine when I execute this in command prompt. Now I want to use this command in C# with variables like this:

```
private int cuttime;
private int wrap;


ffmpeg -i InputStreamURL -acodec aac -strict -2 -vcodec libx264 -hls_wrap wrap -f hls -hls_time cuttime /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8
```

I want to connect these variables with database and with a frontend interface in HTML5.

How can I use c# variables into a ffmpeg command?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create string where all variable arguments are replaced with {0}, {1}, and so on
const string argumentsTemplate = "-i InputStreamURL -acodec aac -strict -2 -vcodec libx264 -hls_wrap {0} -f hls -hls_time {1} /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8";

// String.Format replaces those {0}, {1} with actual values of variables
// {0} with value of first parameter, {1} with value of second parameter, and so on
var arguments = String.Format(argumentsTemplate, wrap, cuttime);

// Start ffmpeg process with actual arguments
Process.Start("ffmpeg", arguments);
```